# Join 2 tables using the combination of 2 columns

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to join two tables. Unfortunately there is no single column to join them. Only the combination of 2 columns (in each of the tables) creates a unique identifier that enables me to make an inner join. How do I do that?

edit: someone suggested making a join using AND. Unfortunately this does not seem to work.

Here is an example of the tablse

Table 1

Order no  |    Operation no | . ...

FWA1     |      10

FWA2     |      20

FWA3     |      10

Table 2

Order no  |    Operation no   |   Description

FWA1       |     **10       |      drilling**

FWA2       |      20        |      grinding

FWA3        |    **10       |      buffing**

(please notice that operation no 10 can have a different description in different orders.)

Comment: Um... just use them both in the join condition then? Hard to give a more specific answer entirely without details.

Comment: Table structure would be helpful.

Comment: Your tables need some [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) first.

Comment: I did not create the tables. I am trying to create a view from our company's navision. sorry I am not an IT person, just a finance guy trying to create a report...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do the job

```
select t1.orderNo, t1.operationNo, t2.description
from Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2 
         on t1.orderNo = t2.orderNo and 
            t1.operationNo = t2.OperationNo
```

Comment: i tried this approach and it shows 0 results. It only works when I make a left or right join, not with an inner join. I am not very good at sql, but i think the problem is that the same operation number can have a different description in different orders

Comment: Well, yes, you could change it to left or a right join based on the table structure.

Comment: the problem is that when i use a right join, it shows the wrong results. e.g. it shows


FWA1 | 10 | drilling and

FWA1 | 10  | buffing

which is incorrect

Comment: what is your expected results?

Comment: the expected result would only be FWA1 | 10 | drilling. For some reason it adds the "buffing" too

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no logic to filter out `FWA3 | 10 | buffing` from the given details unless you hard code it with a where clause. I think you better talk to the IT guy who did the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
SELECT *
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.f1 + t1.f2 = t2.f3
```

On the other hand if you have 2 columns on which you want to join then [DanFromGermany's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17039661/7028) is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 A
    JOIN table2 B ON
    A.first = B.first AND A.second = B.second
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use both columns in JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
```

Answer (score 0):

rIt depends on the relation between the two tables if it's a 1-to-many relation you can join them using two combinations:

```
select *
from table1 a
join table2 b on a.column1 = b.column1 AND a.column2 = b.column2
```

if the relationship between the tables is many-to-many you will need a linking table which would contain a unique id, value1 and value 2 where each row marks a combination of value1 and value2

Hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

Use This Query  :

> **SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;**

Or

> **SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;**